# Dynamically adding links to an element with php

Tags: php, wordpress

Good Day

I am using excerpts in my wordpress theme. Now in wordpress's documentation, they say wordpress does not automatically add links for the excerpts, you have to manually add them like this:

Original excerpts file

```
 <div class="content">
 <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
 </div>
```

Adding links

```
<div class="content">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read More...</a>
</div>
```

Now what I would like to do is to link each excerpt to a different wordpress **page**, and not to its own excerpt. So for that, I would have to create a custom php function to create a unique link for each excerpt, pointing to a different page each. How do I do that?

See my [website](http://gbcgarankuwa.co.za) where the excerpts are located - It is right below the main slider named: Pastor's Corner, Mother's Heart, Sermons etc...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an ID to `get_permalink` to pull the permalink for a different post or page.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id); ?>"> Read More...</a>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink